# How built custom LTI for LMS?

Tags: node.js, scorm, lti, lms

I'm new on LMS amd LTI.
I would like to create my LIT, so that every LMS can use it.
My goal is to read Scorm data from the course.
Do you have any examples, or something practical to look?

Thank you very much